# Animation steps and event data

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-animate

I have just written some code that help you to understand my misunderstanding...

Some code in body:

```
<div id="jeden">
   <p>Jeden.</p>
</div>

<div id="dwa">
   <p>Dwa.</p>
</div>
```

And some jquery code:

```
function blurRad(e) {
   $(this).css({
      "-webkit-filter": "blur(" + e.data.blurRad + "px)",
      "filter": "blur(" + e.data.blurRad + "px)",
      "-moz-filter": "blur(" + e.data.blurRad + "px)",
      "-o-filter": "blur(" + e.data.blurRad + "px)",
      "-ms-filter": "blur(" + e.data.blurRad + "px)"
   });
};

function nowa(e) {
   $(this).before(e.data.nowa);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#dwa').click({nowa: "k"}, nowa);
   $('#jeden').animate({blurRad: 10}, {duration: 2000, step: blurRad}); 
});
```

Now I have a question; why code contained in:

```
   $('#dwa').click({nowa: "k"}, nowa);
```

works, and why code contained in:

```
   $('#jeden').animate({blurRad: 10}, {duration: 2000, step: blurRad});
```

does not want to work?

The same code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g57nkbg2/

Comment: what does it need to do? why do you say "blurRad: 10"?

Comment: Add css style defined in function blurRad via animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it does work. I learn something new.
My old solution is fine, I think:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dwa').click({nowa: "k"}, nowa);
    $('#jeden').css({
        "filter": "blur(10px)",
        "transition": "2s"
    });
});
```

but the mistake in your code is not that. You should change the blurRad function to:

```
function blurRad(e) {
   $(this).css({
      "-webkit-filter": "blur(" + e + "px)",
      "filter": "blur(" + e + "px)",
      "-moz-filter": "blur(" + e + "px)",
      "-o-filter": "blur(" + e + "px)",
      "-ms-filter": "blur(" + e + "px)"
   });
};
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, I can not invent new css propety, however I can name it in my own way, for example potato or blurRad.
Function called potato in action: http://jsfiddle.net/uk006sdy/

If all rguments are misplaced, so where they should be? I just trying to understand my mistake.

Comment: So... what is the difference betwen " this.blurRad " and " e.data.blurRad "? Expect that first one is working and the other not.

Comment: I made it even simpler. The e is the value of the blurRad you passed on to the step function. 'this' depends on where in the code you are; in the css function it refers to the context of the function. It is indeed better not to mess with it too much if you don´t know what is in there, using normal variables is safer.